# How to use seznam mapy within webpack in typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, maps

Seznam mapy (mapy.cz) are great Czech free alternative to google maps with simple API https://api.mapy.cz/.
But how to use them with typescript? Within webpacked aplication?

Comment: Somebody is a Czech. Just Like me. / Někdo je tady Čech. Tak jako já

Comment: Yeah! Exactly! Ahoj!

Answer (score 2):

Seznam mapy (SMap) do not support typesctript and not want to. [Seznam maps forum](https://napoveda.seznam.cz/forum/threads/67230/1)

Maps could not be served from your npm packages, it must be loaded just in time. I prepared a factory, helper and example how to create map.

- Factory loads map scripts and when all things are ready, it call callback funtion **afterInit()**
- Helper can creates map and objects consumed by map object
- Example of map creation
- Official documentation link https://api.mapy.cz/

```js
import SeznamMapHelper from "./SeznamMapHelper";

// Declare global Loader and SMap
declare global {
    interface Window { Loader: any; SMap: any}
}

export default class SeznamMapFactory {
    // Helper for simple creating seznam mapy objects
    private _mapHelper?: SeznamMapHelper;

    public init(afterInit?: ()=>void) {
        afterInit = afterInit || (() => void 0);
        if (!window.Loader) {
            $.getScript('https://api.mapy.cz/loader.js', ()=> {
                window.Loader.async = true;
                window.Loader.load(null, null, afterInit?.bind(this));
            });
        } else {
            afterInit();
        }

    }

    public get helper(): SeznamMapHelper {
        if (!window.Loader) {
            throw Error('Seznam maps: Loader is not initialised. Please init() first.');
        }
        if (!this._mapHelper) {
            this._mapHelper = new SeznamMapHelper;
        }
        return this._mapHelper;
    }
}
```

Helper class creating object consumed by SMap object (map layers, markers, etc.). Helper should be improved to fit your purposes.

```js
// Declare types for Seznam Mapy
declare global {
    interface Window { Loader: any; SMap: any}
}

export type TLayer = {
    setClusterer: (clusterer: TClusterer) => TLayer,
    addMarker: (marker: TMarker|TMarker[]) => TLayer,
    enable: () => void,
    disable: () => void,
    redraw: (full: boolean) => void,
    getId: () => string,
};
export type TClusterer = {};
export type TMarker = {
    click: () => void,
    getId: () => void,
    decorate: (type: any, item: TCard)=>void,
};
export type TCard = {
    setSize: (x:number, y:number)=>TCard,
    getHeader: ()=>Element,
    getFooter: ()=>Element,
    getBody: ()=>Element,
}

export type TMap = {
    addDefaultLayer: ([...any])=>TLayer,
    addLayer: (layer: TLayer)=>TLayer,
    addDefaultControls: ()=>TMap,
    enable: ()=>TMap,
}

export default class SeznamMapHelper {
    public createCoords(gpsLat: number, gpsLng: number): {x:number, y:number} {
        return window.SMap.Coords.fromWGS84(gpsLng, gpsLat); // Seznam map has swapped coords, really.
    }

    public createMap(
        el: Element,
        gpsLat: number,
        gpsLng: number,
        zoom: number = 10
    ): TMap {
        const center = this.createCoords(gpsLat, gpsLng);
        return new window.SMap(el, center, zoom);
    }

    public createDefaultMap(el: Element, gpsLat: number = 50.12655, gpsLng: number = 14.41790): TMap {
        const map = this.createMap(el, gpsLat, gpsLng, 10);
        map.addDefaultLayer(window.SMap.DEF_BASE).enable();
        map.addDefaultControls();
        return map;
    }

    public createMarkerLayer(): TLayer {
        return new window.SMap.Layer.Marker();
    }

    public createClusterer(map: TMap): TClusterer {
        return new window.SMap.Marker.Clusterer(map);
    }

    public createMarker(
        gpsLat: number,
        gpsLng: number,
        id: string|number|undefined = undefined,
        title: string = '',
        url: string|null = null
    ): TMarker {
        const options: any = { title: title };
        if (url) {
             options.url = url;
        }
        return new window.SMap.Marker(this.createCoords(gpsLat, gpsLng), id, options);
    }

    public createCard(marker: TMarker, header: string, body: string, footer:string = '', x: number = 200, y:number = 200): TCard {
        const card: TCard = new window.SMap.Card();
        card.setSize(x, y);
        card.getHeader().innerHTML = header;
        card.getBody().innerHTML = body;
        card.getFooter().innerHTML = footer;
        marker.decorate(window.SMap.Marker.Feature.Card, card);

        return card;
    }
}
```

Example of creating map:

```js
let map: any; // SMap object
let mapContainter = document.getElementById("map"); // Html element to put a map
const mapFactory = new SeznamMapFactory(); // factory object
this.mapFactory.init( () => { // async load of scripts
    map = mapFactory.helper.createDefaultMap(mapContainter); // after load we can use maps
    // other map stuff - markers, layers, etc.
}
```